# mysql select to return blanks for all but first row of repeating column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create a mysql select (directly or using a stored procedure) that will return blanks for repeating columns.  For example, a select that would normally return these 7 records with 2 columns:

```
Bob   123
Bob   557
Bob   888
Joe   887
Joe   223
Tom   899
Tom   999
```

I would prefer to see this directly from the sql select:

```
Bob   123
      557
      888
Joe   887
      223
Tom   899
      999
```

I realize I can just post process the records in my program, but I'd like to replace the duplicates with blanks within the sql call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it would be **very expensive** (subqueries!) and not at all efficient. Whatever language you use or however you transfer this data directly, it's not worth it to have SQL spare these few bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Following should work but it doesn't return the results in the order you've used in your example.

```
SELECT  IF(n.ID = nm.ID, n.Name, NULL)
        , n.ID
FROM    Names n
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  Name
                  , ID = MIN(ID)
          FROM    Names        
          GROUP BY
                  Name
        ) nm ON nm.Name = n.Name
ORDER BY
        n.Name
        , n.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would be a huge waste of resources to not do it through your application, but one way that you could do this is to use [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL)  in a stored procedure or something similar to populate a some temporary table.  With this you could declare a variable for if the name equals the last name that was iterated over.  So if the name is a new name add it to the temporary table otherwise do not.

Again though this is a huge waste of resources

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL (I guess it should be similar for other DBs), to avoid repeating a column value on every row, you can make good use of variables. No subqueries necessary: light and quick.

```
//Init a variable
SET @previous:="";

//Remember previous row value
SELECT IF(Name=@previous, "", @previous:=Name) AS GroupedName, Value
FROM tableName ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Setting & reading the same variable in the same select statemen is undefined behaviour in MySQL, see the manual re variables & assignment.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, here is a select query that will return blanks for repeating column values.

```
SELECT IF(name=@previous, "", @previous:=name) as name_, value
FROM (SELECT @previous:= '') AS temp, tableName
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: If only reading & writing a variable in the same select statement wasn't undefined behaviour.