# Show blank value if the same data exists in other rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that contains a list of my customers' orders, I want to show specific customer's order. The customer can order the same item from time to time:

order_tb:

```
orderid  customerid  itemid    price   quantity   orderdate
   1           2        4      50.00      3       2017-08-02
   1           2       10     150.00      2       2017-08-02
   2           2        6      70.00      6       2017-08-05
   2           2        2      30.00      5       2017-08-05
   2           2        5      38.00      7       2017-08-05
   5           2       10     150.00      3       2017-09-20
   5           2        6      70.00      2       2017-09-20
   2           2        4      50.00      4       2017-09-20
```

Now I use the following select statement. This statement gives me result without error but the problem I don't know how to skip showing the same item from showing and display blank space instead?

```
   SELECT p.itemname, tb.price, tb.quantity, tb.orderdate 
   FROM order_tb tb
   LEFT JOIN product p ON tb.itemid = p.id
   WHERE tb.customerid = 2
```

The query output is:

```
   itemname     price   quantity   orderdate
   football     50.00      3       2017-08-02
   football     50.00      4       2017-09-20
    helmet     150.00      2       2017-08-02
    helmet     150.00      3       2017-09-20
    bulb        70.00      6       2017-08-05
    bulb        70.00      2       2017-09-20
    bucket      30.00      5       2017-08-05
    watch       38.00      7       2017-08-05
```

My expected output:

```
   itemname     price   quantity   orderdate
   football     50.00      3       2017-08-02
                50.00      4       2017-09-20
    helmet     150.00      2       2017-08-02
               150.00      3       2017-09-20
    bulb        70.00      6       2017-08-05
                70.00      2       2017-09-20
    bucket      30.00      5       2017-08-05
    watch       38.00      7       2017-08-05
```

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5668886/6124528

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I can see where you are coming from, this is usually something that is done in the presentation layer (whether that be a reporting tool or an application using the database)

There it is far less processing cost than trying to do it in the query itself which would rely on subqueries or emulating LEAD / LAG functions (as you are using MySQL)