# Left Join but so that left table don't show same data

Tags: mysql

Example

```
+------------+
| Fruits     |
+------------+
| Apple      |
| Banana     |
|            |
+------------+

+------------+
| Color      |
+------------+
| Red        |
| Green      |
| Yellow     |
+------------+
```

And then i'am select with join subquery, get result like this :

```
+-----------------------+
|       Fruits_Color    |
+-----------------------+
| Apple      | Red      |
| Apple      | Green    |
| Banana     | Yellow   |
+------------+----------+
```

But i'am expect result like this :

```
+-----------------------+
| Table Fruits_Color    |
+-----------------------+
| Apple      | Red      |
|            | Green    |
| Banana     | Yellow   |
+------------+----------+
```

This my query :

```
SELECT fruits_name, color_name
FROM fruits f
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM color) c ON c.id = f.color_id;
```

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi. What is the blank entry supposed to be? Explain exactly when blanks should appear. Table rows have no order, so if order is involved explain that too. As with every question, please google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Do you think you are first to ask about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select to return blanks for all but first row of repeating column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668886/mysql-select-to-return-blanks-for-all-but-first-row-of-repeating-column)

Comment: PS Look--I googled 'put blanks instead of duplicate values in the same column mysql' & immediately got answers.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: And LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE) is equivalent to LEFT JOIN TABLE

Answer (score 3):

JOINs do not work the way you want. If there are matches, the query is going to return every column of every matching tuple, even if its value is "repeated" (same as the value of the preceeding row). Anyway, it does not matter as SQL is not concerned with *showing* results, it is concerned with retrieving data.

If you do not want to show "repeated" values, you are free to handle this in your application; in your case it is just that MySQL client does not do any special handling and so it shows every value of every column.

Comment: Well, it *can*, but I agree that it's a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Rather than leaving blanks, the 'normal' approach to this in mysql would be to return a single row for each fruit/colour combo with a GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT() for the colours. e.g.

```
select f.name, group_concat(c.colour) 
from fruits f join fruit_colours fc on (f.id = fc.fid) 
join colours c on (c.id = fc.cid) 
group by f.name; 

+--------+------------------------+
| name   | group_concat(c.colour) |
+--------+------------------------+
| apple  | red,green              |
| banana | yellow                 |
+--------+------------------------+
```