# Hide data for all but first row on left join column

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have this query for a view:

```
select a.name as Author,b.name as Book
from a
left join b on a.id = b.a_id
```

and it produces this output:

```
Brandon Sanderson Mistborn
Brandon Sanderson Way of Kings
Brandon Sanderson Steelheart
Patrick Rothfuss  The Wise Man's Fear
Patrick Rothfuss  The Name of the Wind
```

All good so far, but I'd like to hide the duplicates in the left row:

```
Brandon Sanderson Mistborn
                  Way of Kings
                  Steelheart
Patrick Rothfuss  The Wise Man's Fear
                  The Name of the Wind
```

That makes is easier to read IMO, and it's the formatting I want for this view.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's not really something you do in SQL. Fix it in an above presentation layer instead.

Comment: What dbms you use now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select to return blanks for all but first row of repeating column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668886/mysql-select-to-return-blanks-for-all-but-first-row-of-repeating-column)

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS I just googled 'sql site:stackoverflow.com blank out all but the first row for a value in a table'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this can be implemented by a `window function`, if the database what you use now supports this feature such as PostgreSQL or MySQL of high version(8.0+), you can write the SQL as below:

```
select * from books;
      author       |         book         
-------------------+----------------------
 Brandon Sanderson | Mistborn
 Brandon Sanderson | Way of Kings
 Brandon Sanderson | Steelheart
 Patrick Rothfuss  | The Wise Man’s Fear
 Patrick Rothfuss  | The Name of the Wind
(5 rows)

select
    case when row_number() over(partition by author order by book) > 1 then null else author end as author,
    book
from
    books;
      author       |         book         
-------------------+----------------------
 Brandon Sanderson | Mistborn
                   | Steelheart
                   | Way of Kings
 Patrick Rothfuss  | The Name of the Wind
                   | The Wise Man's Fear
(5 rows)

with tmp as (
select
    author,
    book,
    row_number() over(partition by author order by book) as sort
from
    books
)
select
    case when sort>1 then null else author end as th_author,
    book
from
    tmp
order by
    author,sort;
     th_author     |         book         
-------------------+----------------------
 Brandon Sanderson | Mistborn
                   | Steelheart
                   | Way of Kings
 Patrick Rothfuss  | The Name of the Wind
                   | The Wise Man‘s Fear
```

Or the database does not support `window function`, you can write as below:

```
with named_book as (
select
    author,
    min(book) as book
from
    books
group by
    author
)
select
    b.author,
    a.book
from
    books a
left join
    named_book b on a.book = b.book
order by
    a.author,a.book;
      author       |         book         
-------------------+----------------------
 Brandon Sanderson | Mistborn
                   | Steelheart
                   | Way of Kings
 Patrick Rothfuss  | The Name of the Wind
                   | The Wise Man's Fear
(5 rows)
```

Comment: was hoping for some sort of syntax that didn't complicate the query as much, but now I know it has to be like this unless I do it in the presentation layer. Anyway it solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you would typically do in SQL.  A table has rows and columns and -- generally -- the value sin a row should be independent of other rows.

You can do this using `row_number()`, being careful about the sort criteria:

```
select (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by a.id order by b.name)
             then a.name
        end) as Author,
       b.name as Book
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.a_id
order by a.id, b.name;
```

It is very important that the outer `order by` keys match the keys in the `partition by` and `order by` clauses.

You might find it more useful to create one row per author.  The syntax varies among databases, but I think the standard function is `listagg()`:

```
select a.name as Author,
       listagg(b.name, '; ') within group (order by b.name) as Book
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.a_id
group by a.name;
```

Comment: You're right, it can be solved in one of these ways but neither feels ideal. In this particular case I have no presentation layer, I will have to choose to use one of these solutions or to accept the query as is. Thank you!

Comment: @CodeOrElse . . . You should get used to seeing tables as *tables* with complete rows.